# Image rotation in MatLab

Tags: image, matlab, computer-vision, image-rotation

I am very new to MatLab and am trying to rotate an image within an axes so the user can get it inline, once the image rotates once I can't get it to call back and rotate again..

```
img2 = imread('pic.png');
axes(handles.axes2);
imshow(imrotate(img2,3))
```

in the push_button callback I call rotate, how can I let the user rotate the image as many times as they wish.

Any help would be great,

Thanks

Comment: You don't save the rotated image, so it is re-loaded every time. Save the image (`img2`) into `handles`, and rotate *that* image and display.